# Creating Google Chart in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-visualization

I was reading this http://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/20/load-google-chart-by-ajax-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/ and this https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.

How can I create an array like this in VB.NET?

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);
```

I need to create it from a query, not from static data like in the article I linked to above:

```
Dim water = db.Tbl_Hydrations.Where(Function(x) x.Hyd_Create_Date >= firstDay And x.Hyd_Create_Date <= lastDay).ToList
```

If I can create the array, I can display the data in the chart.  Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

I tried this:

```
Function WeightAreaChartData() As JsonResult

    Dim data = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    data.Add("1", New With {.Name = "China", .Value = "11"})
    data.Add("2", New With {.Name = "China", .Value = "11"})

    Return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

End Function
```

But, Google Charts says, "No Data."

The JSON it returns is:

```
{"1":{"Name":"China","Value":"11"},"2":{"Name":"China","Value":"11"}}
```

**Final Edit:**

This is the action I'm using:

```
<EmployeeAuthorize()>
Function WeightAreaChartData() As JsonResult

    Dim myData = db.Tbl_Weights.Where(Function(x) x.Weight_Employee_ID).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Weight_Create_Date)

    Dim data = New List(Of Object)

    data.Add(New Object() {"Date", "Your Weight"})

    For Each i As Tbl_Weight In myData

        data.Add(New Object() {DateTime.Parse(i.Weight_Create_Date).Day, i.Weight_Amount})

    Next

    Return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

End Function
```

Comment: Can you add the json result that WeightAreaChartData returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this array:

```
[
   ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
   ['2004',  1000,      400],
   ['2005',  1170,      460],
   ['2006',  660,       1120],
   ['2007',  1030,      540]
]
```

By using this JsonResult

```
Function WeightAreaChartData() As JsonResult
    Dim data = New Object() {
                   New Object() {"Year", "Sales", "Expenses"},
                   New Object() {"2004", 1000, 400},
                   New Object() {"2005", 1170, 460},
                   New Object() {"2006", 660, 1120},
                   New Object() {"2007", 1030, 540}
              }


    Return Json(data, JsonRequest.Behavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

There's more to your question than this, I know. But this should point you in the right direction.  Feel free to comment for more advice.

**EDIT**

Taking the [example from you original post](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart)

You can rewrite it to use the JsonResult (change the /Controller/WeightAreaChartData to point to your JsonResult route)

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            $.post('/Controller/WeightAreaChartData', {},
                function (data) {
                    var tdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

                    var options = {
                        title: 'Company Performance',
                        hAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' } }
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(tdata, options);
                });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that does answer my question and I do have more questions.  For instance, how can I use JSON to get it into the Google Chart?  This page has JSON in a specific format (at the bottom) https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Comment: This is the actual param list, I think I have to build an object that will create json like this https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam.  Then I have to try to make the object get created dynamically from my database using a query.

Comment: There are numerous ways to achieve your goal.  Based upon what we've already done, I'd use the arrayToDataTable function as shown in the edit.

Comment: Michael, thank you so much!  This puts me closer.  Now, I just have to be able to get the data from a query.  I think I just have to make my query and then loop through and create objects for each row.

Comment: That's the way I'd go about it.

Comment: Michael, again, thank you so much.  I am sure this will help others, too, as I could find no good resources on this anywhere.